# Azure pipeline failed to checkout recursive submodule

Tags: azure-devops

failed to checkout recursive submodule

checkout: self
submodule: recursive
persistCredentials: true

logs:
git submodule sync --recursive
synchronizing submodule url for xxx
synchronizing submodule url for xxx

git --config-env=http.http://xxxx:8080.extraheader=env var http.http://xxxx:8080.extraheader submodule --init --force --recursive

fatal: cannot prompt because terminal prompt have been disabled

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you might have a scenario where a different set of credentials are needed to access the submodules. This can happen, for example, if your main repository and submodule repositories aren't stored in the same Azure DevOps organization.

To solve the issue, please refer [Alternative to using the Checkout submodules option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#alternative-to-using-the-checkout-submodules-option).

Here are the detailed steps:

1. Create a [personal access token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#create-a-pat) in the organization of the submodule repo.
2. Prefix the PAT with `pat:` and [base64-encode](https://www.base64encode.org/) this prefixed string to create a basic auth token.

[image]

3. Create a Variable named `secret` and the value is the basic auth token in step 2.

[image]
[image]

4. Update the yaml

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: false
  persistCredentials : true
- bash: |
    git -c http.https://dev.azure.com/{SubmoduleOrgName}/{SubmoduleProjectName}/_git/{SubmoduleRepoName}.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic $(secret)" submodule update --init --recursive
```

5. My test result

[image]